# extract multipart 7z files in centOS terminal

Tags: centos, 7z

How do I extract multipart 7z files (doc.7z.001, doc.7z.002...., doc.7z.060) in centOS terminal? I tried concatenating all the parts to a single file using this command below,

```
cat doc.7z* > ./docs.7z
```

and extracted the file using this command,

```
7za x docs.7z
```

which gives me this error,

```
    Scanning the drive for archives: 1 file, 32937135758 bytes (31 GiB)

Extracting archive: docs.7z ERROR: docs.7z docs.7z Open ERROR: Can not open the file as [7z] archive


ERRORS: Unexpected end of archive
     Can't open as archive: 1 Files: 0 Size:       0 Compressed: 0
```

Comment: Would `7za x doc.7z.001` work?

Comment: That didnt work either. Open ERROR: Can not open the file as [7z] archive

Answer (score 1):

## Setting the stage

Let's first create an input file.

```
$ dd if=/dev/random of=in bs=512 count=10
10+0 records in
10+0 records out
5120 bytes (5.1 kB, 5.0 KiB) copied, 0.00056488 s, 9.1 MB/s
```

What's in the dir?

```
$ ls -l
total 8
-rw-r----- 1 tomasz tomasz 5120 Jul 31 18:37 in
```

Now let's build a multipart archive.

```
$ 7z a -v1k arch in

7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=en_GB.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,2 CPUs Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     U9400  @ 1.40GHz (1067A),ASM)

Scanning the drive:
1 file, 5120 bytes (5 KiB)

Creating archive: arch.7z

Items to compress: 1

    
Files read from disk: 1
Archive size: 5238 bytes (6 KiB)
Everything is Ok
```

Result?

```
$ ls
arch.7z.001  arch.7z.002  arch.7z.003  arch.7z.004  arch.7z.005  arch.7z.006  in
```

Let's now move the old input file out of the way.

```
$ mv in in.o && ls
arch.7z.001  arch.7z.002  arch.7z.003  arch.7z.004  arch.7z.005  arch.7z.006  in.o
```

## Solution 1

Now it's time to extract the file back.

```
$ 7z e -ai'!arch.*' -an

7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=en_GB.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,2 CPUs Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     U9400  @ 1.40GHz (1067A),ASM)

Scanning the drive for archives:
6 files, 5238 bytes (6 KiB)
    
Extracting archive: arch.7z.001
--
Path = arch.7z.001
Type = Split
Physical Size = 1024
Volumes = 6
Total Physical Size = 5238
----
Path = arch.7z
Size = 5238
--
Path = arch.7z
Type = 7z
Physical Size = 5238
Headers Size = 114
Method = LZMA2:6k
Solid = -
Blocks = 1

Everything is Ok
      
Size:       5120
Compressed: 5238
```

Take a look, what we have now.

```
$ ls
arch.7z.001  arch.7z.002  arch.7z.003  arch.7z.004  arch.7z.005  arch.7z.006  in  in.o
```

So the `in` file is back. Is it the same as the `in.o`?

```
$ diff in in.o && echo same
same
```

No output from `diff` would be enough.

### Explanation

The action line is this one:

```
7z e -ai'!arch.*' -an
```

The full command is composed of these elements:

- `7z` is the base command
- `e` stands for extraction
- `-ai` picks archives to include. This option seems canonical across various versions of 7z, or maybe a standard for compilation, I'm not sure. But it can be found online, for example [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/7z). Its syntax is `-ai[r[-|0]]{@listfile|!wildcard}` and I will only explain the option I'm using. The others can be figured out with the help of documentation. The one I used is `!wildcard` and this seems to follow the common globbing patterns, but for the initial `!`, which introduces this choice.
- `-an` is defined on my system this way, `-an : disable archive_name field`. It is indeed not to be found in the popular online documentation like [this one](https://linux.die.net/man/1/7z). Again, either it is compilation or version specific. It makes the logic cleaner, as the general command syntax is relaxed. More on this follows.

The command is presented so:

```
7z <command> [<switches>... ] <archive_name> [<file_names>... ] [<@listfiles>... ]
```

Archive name in this notation is obligatory, in opposition to the parameters marked with `[` and `]`. What `-an` does is lifting this obligation.

When `7z` is used without it, the result is such:

```
$ 7z e -ai'!arch.*'

7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=en_GB.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,2 CPUs Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     U9400  @ 1.40GHz (1067A),ASM)



Command Line Error:
Cannot find archive name
```

However, it can be negotiated by just using *any* name as the obligatory parameter. It will be filtered out anyhow.

Check again, what's in the dir:

```
$ ls
arch.7z.001  arch.7z.002  arch.7z.003  arch.7z.004  arch.7z.005  arch.7z.006  in.o
```

And the following can be done.

```
$ 7z e -ai'!arch.*' asdf

7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=en_GB.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,2 CPUs Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     U9400  @ 1.40GHz (1067A),ASM)

Scanning the drive for archives:
6 files, 5238 bytes (6 KiB)
    
Extracting archive: arch.7z.001
--
Path = arch.7z.001
Type = Split
Physical Size = 1024
Volumes = 6
Total Physical Size = 5238
----
Path = arch.7z
Size = 5238
--
Path = arch.7z
Type = 7z
Physical Size = 5238
Headers Size = 114
Method = LZMA2:6k
Solid = -
Blocks = 1

Everything is Ok
      
Size:       5120
Compressed: 5238
```

The new state of the dir:

```
$ ls
arch.7z.001  arch.7z.002  arch.7z.003  arch.7z.004  arch.7z.005  arch.7z.006  in  in.o
```

And the outcome should be correct.

```
$ sha224sum in in.o
fde74a72c7f4079db4ca18d96629a4f316cd76324bda9742cb2d6c5c  in
fde74a72c7f4079db4ca18d96629a4f316cd76324bda9742cb2d6c5c  in.o
```

### Documentation

The `-an` switch is documented both in [Debian's 7zz man](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/7zip/7zz.1.en.html), on my Debian Bullseye derivative man of 7z and in the official source for [v. 22.01](https://www.7-zip.org/a/7z2201-src.tar.xz) as downloadable [here](https://www.7-zip.org/download.html).

The exact reason is hard to trace, why the `-an` option is not documented in some case. From what I have found, it may be worth trying out, even if not documented by its man. The reason for this is that there seems to be a discrepancy in the documentation of p7zip, which is also to be expected on CentOS. The source code for man, as can be seen [here](https://github.com/jinfeihan57/p7zip/tree/master/man1), does not document this switch. At the same time, it is mentioned in multiple other places in the same source base. (The same master branch as of today.)

```
$ grep -rPI '\B-an\b'
CPP/7zip/UI/Console/Main.cpp:    "  -an : disable archive_name field\n"
CPP/7zip/UI/P7ZIP/wxP7ZIP.cpp:static LPCWSTR kArchiveNoNameSwitch = L" -an";
CPP/7zip/UI/Common/CompressCall.cpp:static const char *kArcIncludeSwitches = " -an -ai";
CPP/7zip/UI/Common/CompressCall.cpp:    params.AddAscii(" -an");
GUI/p7zipForFilemanager:    ${P7ZIP} t -an -ai@${list}
GUI/p7zipForFilemanager:    ${P7ZIP} x ${flag_ad} -an -ai@${list}
GUI/p7zipForFilemanager:    ${P7ZIP} x ${flag_ad} -o"*" -an -ai@${list}
DOC/MANUAL/cmdline/commands/list.htm:  <A href="../switches/ar_no.htm">-an (Disable parsing of archive_name)</A><BR>
DOC/MANUAL/cmdline/commands/test.htm:  <A href="../switches/ar_no.htm">-an (Disable parsing of archive_name)</A><BR>
DOC/MANUAL/cmdline/commands/extract.htm:  <A href="../switches/ar_no.htm">-an (Disable parsing of archive_name)</A><BR>
DOC/MANUAL/cmdline/commands/extract_full.htm:  <A href="../switches/ar_no.htm">-an (Disable parsing of archive_name)</A><BR>
DOC/MANUAL/cmdline/switches/index.htm:<TR> <TD><A href="ar_no.htm">-an</A></TD> <TD><A href="ar_no.htm">Disable parsing of archive_name</A></TD></TR>
DOC/MANUAL/cmdline/switches/ar_include.htm:7z t -an -air!*.7z
DOC/MANUAL/cmdline/switches/ar_include.htm:  <A href="ar_no.htm">-an (Disable parsing of archive_name)</A>
DOC/MANUAL/cmdline/switches/ar_exclude.htm:7z t -an -ai!*.7z -ax!a*.7z
DOC/MANUAL/cmdline/switches/ar_exclude.htm:  <A href="ar_no.htm">-an (Disable parsing of archive_name)</A>
DOC/MANUAL/cmdline/switches/bs.htm:7z a -si -so -bsp2 -txz -an < file.tar > file.tar.xz
DOC/MANUAL/cmdline/switches/ar_no.htm:  <TITLE>-an (Disable parsing of archive_name) switch</TITLE>
DOC/MANUAL/cmdline/switches/ar_no.htm:<H1>-an (Disable parsing of archive_name) switch</H1>
DOC/MANUAL/cmdline/switches/ar_no.htm:-an
DOC/MANUAL/cmdline/switches/ar_no.htm:7z t -an -ai!*.7z -ax!a*.7z
```

I won't go into a deeper investigation. My guess is that the man page was neglected at some point, or possibly there was a failed merge. Still, it is interesting that in Debian it is fine. Solving this deserves a separate bounty. And the winner is me, because [this is the patch](https://sources.debian.org/patches/p7zip/16.02+dfsg-6/09-man-update.patch/).

I can't yet find any official nor unofficial explanation of how to cope without the `-an` switch.

## Another solution

I'm doing a deeper investigation and I must admit the syntax is weird and not that well documented.

Here's another solution, for which I have no official explanation yet.

```
$ 7z e .

7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=en_GB.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,2 CPUs Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     U9400  @ 1.40GHz (1067A),ASM)

Scanning the drive for archives:
7 files, 10358 bytes (11 KiB)
    
Extracting archive: ./arch.7z.001
--
Path = ./arch.7z.001
Type = Split
Physical Size = 1024
Volumes = 6
Total Physical Size = 5238
----
Path = arch.7z
Size = 5238
--
Path = arch.7z
Type = 7z
Physical Size = 5238
Headers Size = 114
Method = LZMA2:6k
Solid = -
Blocks = 1

Everything is Ok

Extracting archive: ./in.o
ERROR: ./in.o
Can not open the file as archive

    
Archives: 2
OK archives: 1
Can't open as archive: 1
Size:       5120
Compressed: 5238

$ diff in in.o && echo same
same
```

Notice the `arch.*` series is correctly recognised, while `in.o` is just dismissed as another archive, an unopenable one though.

### Explanation

Autodetection is all I can say.

### Documentation

none yet

## Other notes

I'm not sure about the difference between using `diff` and `cmp` for checking sameness here. I always use `diff` and it always did, what I expected. A simple test of it being able to handle binaries, continuing with the previously used files:

```
$ echo x >> in
$ diff in in.o
Binary files in and in.o differ
```

Comment: Please explain how this works.  I glanced at the man page, and I didn’t see an explanation for **`-an`**.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … P.S.  `random` data is not text.  It’s probably better to use `cmp` rather than `diff`.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' Take a look. Thanks.

Comment: Wow!  I’m too lazy to verify that this is actually correct, but I’m up voting it for level of effort.  And thanks for educating me a little on the way ``diff`` handles binary files.  I’ll probably continue to use ``cmp`` — partly out of force of habit, partly because it’s one character shorter — but it’s good to know. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  By the way — and I can’t find this documented anywhere — it looks like `7z` can extract multiple archives with a single command if they (the archives) can be specified with a single wildcard.  Try `7z e *` or `7z e foo*`.  And, if you specify a directory name for the archive name, it automatically processes all file(s) in that directory (like `grep -r`) — try `7z e /a/b/c/dirname`.  So it looks like `7z e .` is equivalent to `7z e *`.

Comment: Update: Oops. I tested the above in Windows (Command Prompt), not Unix, so the wildcard technique probably won’t actually work in Unix. But still I guess that directory name means “all files in this directory”.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' Thanks. I've just added a tiny bit more about documentation. See in changelog. `*` vs `.` is quite expected. But as for the likeness to grep, you need to remember about the "recurse type" `r[- | 0]`, which introduces a complication in comparison to grep. And my manual says `-r-` is the default, and it means "Disable recurse subdirectories."

Comment: Well, for such a big project as 7-Zip seems to be, the documentation that I’ve been able to find is not as good as I would expect. Based on what I could find, though, it sort-of looks like the ``r`` flag applies to the *file names* (if any) and (maybe) not the *archive name.*

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' I'm not sure what you mean. As for `*` vs `.`, there's a weirdness there. In my example `*` doesn't do the thing unless the output is already present. If it's not correct, it gets corrected. But if it's not present, then well - too bad! Still, the way described in the other answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
7z -v100m
```

This will split the archive into 100MB files.

7z -v option supports b k m g (bytes, kilobytes, megabytes, gigabytes

source Ref: https://superuser.com/questions/258872/split-files-on-windows-compatible-with-linux-cat

Answer (score 0):

Just

```
7za x doc.7z.001
```

without concatenation.

If it dosn't work you have broken or renamed files.

Check content of doc.7z.001

```
hexdump -C -n 32 doc.7z.001
```

must contain 7z in first two bytes

and with

```
file doc.7z.001
```

must say that is 7zip archive.